# "Multiple Definitions" at the same line in C

Tags: c, kernel

So I'm making a function called reboot, but when I define it the compiler gives an error like the function is already defined.

Here is bios.c:

```c
#include "bios.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <libasm/asm.h>
void reboot()
{
    uint8_t good = 0x02;
    while (good & 0x02)
        good = EmeraldASM_inb(0x64);
    EmeraldASM_outb(0x64, 0xFE);
    asm volatile("hlt");
}
```

here is bios.h :

```c
#ifndef BIOSPOWER_H
#define BIOSPOWER_H
#pragma once
void reboot();
extern void shutdown();
#endif
```

here is the compiler error: `` /home/abbix/Documents/Projects/emerald/src/firmware/bios.c:5: multiple definition of `reboot'; src/firmware/bios.o:/home/abbix/Documents/Projects/emerald/src/firmware/bios.c:5: first defined here ``

Here is my Makefile:

https://pastebin.com/xCcQEtx3

Comment: is that the full message? there should possibly be a note to the second definition

Comment: yes it is, here is the full compiling log: https://imgur.com/a/WYfYq87

Comment: Can you show your Makefile?

Comment: Yes, I added a link to the post

Comment: Aside, `void reboot()` should be `void reboot(void)`

Comment: Search on all the source code files: there might be another `reboot` function implemented somewhere. Also, make sure to execute `make clean` to remove all intermediary object files (.o) before building it again.

Comment: Post your build log (it is a build log, not a compiling log, because it does all of the build, including linking, not just compiling) as copied-and-pasted text in the question, not as a a link to a reduced-resolution image in an external site. Do `make clean` first. You can use the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags when posting text to Stack Overflow to mark it as performatted text.

Comment: or you might have `#include "bios.c"` somewhere too.

Comment: Make sure the full link command is shown in the log. In the makefile, remove the `@` characters that tell `make` to suppress display of the commands.

Comment: Why is there a blank line between `$(KERNEL_ELF): $(OBJ)` and `@$(LD) $(LDHARDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@`?

Comment: I already tried make clean and it is the same result. I will try removing the @

Comment: @Abb1x: The purpose of doing `make clean` before generating the build log is not to ensure some old incorrect intermediate file is not lying around but to ensure that all commands are executed again so that we can see them in the build log.

Comment: oh, I see it looks like the file is linked twice, do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my assembly file had the name bios.asm, so it created two bios.o that was what caused the error (thanks to Eric Postpischil)